# pouchDB only processing one put request in loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, couchdb, pouchdb, ng-file-upload

For some reason when I send a put request with an attachment, only one put requests goes through. Can anyone spot my mistake? I really don't know why this would be happening.

This is the `consolelog()` I get. Notice how only one file completes but it is cycling through both files.

```
[Log] file1.PDF (app.js, line 887)
[Log] file2.PDF (app.js, line 887)
[Log] {ok: true, id: "te366a21a-b9a4-449a-97c3-7a38bbc6c8ef", rev: "1-da5d4c740cd6eaef3840b55f194b6abc"} (app.js, line 907)
```

Here is my function that cycles through all of the files added:

```
$scope.startUpload = function() {

    var files = $scope.file_upload.file_array;

    $scope.file_upload.statusLog = new Array(files.length);
    $scope.file_upload.uploadArray = new Array(files.length);

    if (files && files.length) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) 
        {
            var file = files[i];
            if (!file.$error) 
            {
                $scope.upload(file);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the function that runs for each file that is suppose to upload and create the couchdb document.

```
$scope.upload = function(file) {

    Upload.base64DataUrl(file).then(function(data){

        console.log(file.name);

        var attachment = {};
        var attachment_info = { 
            content_type: file.type,
            data: data.replace('data:application/pdf;base64,', '')
        };
        attachment[file.name] = attachment_info;

        $pouchDB.db.put({
          _id: 't'+uuid(),
          _attachments: attachment
        })
        .then(function(data){
             console.log(data);
        });

    })
}
```

Comment: Do you see the document inserted in the db tho ?

Comment: While nothing seems to be wrong, it's possible the first `put` `promise` is still `pending` and pouchdb is not ready for the second document and silently fails..(you probably already knew that). 
Consider using `db.bulkDocs()`  https://pouchdb.com/api.html#batch_create instead.